# Troubleshooting "Out of Memory Error: Metaspace" in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

While working in development mode in Play for Scala (2.5.x), after around three hours of changing code and hot-deploying, Play hungs with the error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace`.

After some research, the problem seems to be that the application instantiates Java objects (such as factories and connections) that Play is not aware of, and when Play restarts these objects stay in memory causing leaks. The solution is to clean up components when Play shuts down as explained [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up), or to destroy them  after they are used.

The problem is that I clean up all these objects and still get `OutOfMemoryError`. I tried with Java's `jconsole` to find out what classes are creating the leak and how much memory they are taking, but couldn't find much. Any ideas how to deal with this situation? I don't want to simply increase memory without knowing what's going on.

PS: This seems to be a common issue, it would be great if Play itself provided the tools to detect the problem.

Comment: That's rather usual in dev with incremental compilations, you can have a look at the options suggested at https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/scala/JVMMemoryOnDev.html

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to analyze the problem before increasing memory, I want to get rid of the issue in case it would create complications in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this problem seems unevitable, currently. Although, it got better in Play 2.6, I still run into this.

And this has nothing to do with components not getting cleaned up, the metaspace is the place where classes are loaded. Play (dynamically) creates a lot of classes (e.g. anonymous classes) when compiling and each of those classes adds to the metaspace, which eventually gets filled up.

My suggestion would be to just increase the `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` until you can work for a few hours without this exception. Then, restart sbt once in a while. I use 500 MB currently, which seems to be fine (it is usually 128MB with the SBT launcher):

```
sbt -J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=500m
```

This is usually no problem in production, since you have a fixed number of classes loaded (no compilation in production).

Comment: The problem seems more frequent when I don't clean up some Java libraries that I use. Could it be a combination of these and Play compilation classes?

Comment: yes, that's possible. but the most likely culprit is reloading classes with some classloader magic due to recompilation.